# C# linq, get a list of distinct values of a object property, with null check in a groupby query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hey I have a object being grouped to get a number of queries. For one of the properties SchoolInfoType I want to get  list of all the distinct properties typeValues (property of SchoolInfoType) where typeName (property of schoolInfoType) = recess in a string list, but I can't seem to get it to work. School Info type may also be null so I also need to do a null check on properties. Final return type I want is List.

What I have so far, seems to be making a double enumerable, when I really only want 1.

Example code

```
var data = session.GroupBy(x => x.SchoolId).Select( a => new SchoolObject { 
StudentHours = a.Sum(m => m.Hours),

// Query I tried but doesnt return correct return type end up getting embedded enumerables
// need the null check to prevent exception on comparing on null type, end result should 
be list of unique type values matching where conditions
Types = a.Where( x => x.SchoolInfoType != null)
.Select( t => t.SchoolInfoType.Where(d => d.typeName == "recess")
.Select(n => n.TypeValue).Distinct))

}).ToList();
```

Structure of School Info Type Object relevant info

```
public class SchoolInfoType {
public string TypeName {get; set; }
public string TypeValue {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The code shown in the post does not compile. Please review [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question. Make sure to split your monstrous single line attempt into individual lines, with one variable per line and figure out which of them does not do what you expect it to do. Than provide just that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The internal select is what is causing the nested output

```
Types = a.Where(x => x.SchoolInfoType != null)
         .Select(x => x.SchoolInfoType)
         .Where(x => x.typeName == "recess")
         .Select(n => n.TypeValue)
         .Distinct()
         .ToList();
```

Your query is asking for `IEnumerable` of `TypeValue`'s that is distinct and == recess, filtered from an `IEnumerable` that was filtered on nulls. This sort of nesting is unclear and is the cause of the end result being a nested `IEnumerable`. You are selecting within a select

A Select is going to produce you an `IEnumerable`, so selecting within another select is going to get you nesting. Not to mention the time and space complexity is going to suffer when it steps down the IL to nested loops

Comment: typeName is a property of SchoolInfoType not of x

Comment: if I try to add the 2 properties in same query it will not compile and give error a.Where(x => x.SchoolInfoType != null && x.SchoolInfoType.Where(l => l.typeName == "recess"))

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated my answer to chain 2 where statements together, since the 2nd clause must filter on the resulting Ienumerable of the 1st filter

Comment: x in the second where still only returns the  filtered original type. typeName is a property of SchoolInfoType not X so I don't have access to it in the second where, because it is a embedded property of schoolinfotype. SchoolInfoType != x

Comment: Updated again. To be clear, we filter on nulls, and then project a ienumerable of `SchoolInfoType`, then we filter on 'recess' and select out the ienumerable of `TypeValue`, and then lastly you need a list of distinct values. Does that sound accurate? The type hierarchy is confusing me here, sorry

Comment: yes that is correct, but unfortunately the query will break on the 2nd where, when I try to select on it using that logic, it only gives me access to Ienumerable functions not object properties

Comment: Can you copy the error/warning message from the compiler here. I messed up the lambda on 2nd where clause, updated it

Comment: It won't give a error but it just wont give access to SchoolInfotType properties, instead it will only give access to Ienumerable properties such as Remove, Contains, Add etc...

Comment: That may just be your IDE/intellisense acting badly, I don't know how to help with that. Type the query out manually and run it, if there are no errors then the code should be able to compile and run. Check to see if you got your expected list

Comment: It will say that property doesnt exist in the current context